# Accessing my WPF COM Library from Python

Tags: c#, python, wpf, com, python.net

I'd like to run my WPF application from a python script, however am having difficulty.
To achieve this I have converted the WPF application to a COM library as follows:

```
namespace MyWpfApp
{

[Guid("F75D3377-D677-41BF-B3D5-C677C442228F")]
public interface IMyWpfAppInterface
{
    void ShowCOMDialog();
    void ClickButton1();
    void ClickButton2();
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("D936A84B-8B1C-4D62-B090-C06E3EB5EEE9")]
public class MyWpfClass : IMyWpfAppInterface
{
    private static Thread m_runDlgThread;
    private static MainWindow m_mainWindow = null;
    private static Application m_app = null;

    public MyWpfClass() { }

    public void ShowCOMDialog()
    {
        m_msgHelper = new MessageHelper();
        m_runDlgThread = new Thread(runDlg);
        m_runDlgThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        m_runDlgThread.Start();
    }

    public void ClickButton1(){// to do}
    public void ClickButton2(){// to do}

    private void runDlg()
    {
        Application m_app = new Application();
        m_mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        m_app.Run(m_mainWindow);
    }
}
}
```

I have installed my assembly to the global assembly cache and registered the dll as follows

```
gacutil.exe" /i MyWpfApp.dll 
REGASM MyWpfApp.dll /tlb:com.MyWpfApp.tlb
```

I have tested that I can successfully import the Typelib and run my WPF application from a win32 console application.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#import "..\MyWpfApp\bin\Debug\com.MyWpfApp.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
CoInitialize(NULL);   //Initialize all COM Components

// <namespace>::<InterfaceName>
MyWpfApp::IMyWpfAppInterfacePtr pDotNetCOMPtr;

// CreateInstance parameters
// e.g. CreateInstance (<namespace::CLSID_<ClassName>)
HRESULT hRes = 
    pDotNetCOMPtr.CreateInstance(MyWpfApp::CLSID_MyWpfClass);
if (hRes == S_OK)
{
    const DWORD cTimeout_ms = 500;
    HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
    BSTR str;
    pDotNetCOMPtr->ShowCOMDialog ();
    bool toggle = true;
    while(true)
    {
        DWORD dwWait = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent,cTimeout_ms);
        if(toggle)
        {
            pDotNetCOMPtr->ClickButton1();
            toggle = false;
        }
        else
        {
            pDotNetCOMPtr->ClickButton2();
            toggle = true;
        }

    }
    //call .NET COM exported function ShowDialog ()
}

CoUninitialize ();   //DeInitialize all COM Components
return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to access the COM component from Python

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as c
myWpf = win32com.client.Dispatch("MyWpfApp.MyWpfClass")
```

This fails, reporting

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

I can see the class "MyWpfApp.MyWpfClass" int the registry and also from OLE Viewer.
I've done this kind of thing many times for a C++ based application without any problems. However this was with either an ATL project or MFC app with automation switched on. In this case I have converted WPF application to a dll and converted to COM by hand.
Could someone please advise what else I need to do to run the app from python?

Thanks in advance.

Further Edit :
I can load the typelib in python but still can't access the com class
I ran

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom


myApp = pythoncom.LoadTypeLib("D:\\MyWorkSpace\\testProgs\\ATL_COM\\WPF\MyWpfApp\\MyWpfApp\\bin\\Debug\\com.MyWpfApp.tlb")
downloads_stat = None

for index in xrange(0, myApp.GetTypeInfoCount()):
    type_name = myApp.GetDocumentation(index)[0]
    type_iid = myApp.GetTypeInfo(index).GetTypeAttr().iid
    print type_iid
    print type_name
    if type_name == 'MyWpfClass':
        downloads_stat = win32com.client.Dispatch(type_iid)
```

This confirms that the classes are loaded but I can't access them because they are reported as not registered.

```
>>> 
{B5E3A6C6-09A0-315C-BF3A-CB943389F610}
MessageHelper
{FBE23BB0-3EDC-3A65-90EB-DF84F7545D70}
COPYDATASTRUCT
{8BEE824F-F708-3052-BC21-A9EC4E1BB002}
MainWindow
{8C0044EF-91A9-3CB3-9945-1ACA076F3D7E}
NextPrimeDelegate
{F75D3377-D677-41BF-B3D5-C677C442228F}
IMyWpfAppInterface
{D936A84B-8B1C-4D62-B090-C06E3EB5EEE9}
MyWpfClass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MyWorkSpace\testProgs\ATL_COM\WPF\MyWpfApp\MyWin32App\Python\MyPythonClient.py", line 15, in <module>
    downloads_stat = win32com.client.Dispatch(type_iid)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
>>>
```

I can also confirm that there is an entry 'MyWpfApp.MyWpfClass' in the registry with the class id {D936A84B-8B1C-4D62-B090-C06E3EB5EEE9}.

Further Edit:

I tried installing Python for .Net and ran the following command

```
import clr;
import sys
sys.path.append('D:\\MyWorkSpace\\testProgs\\ATL_COM\\WPF\\MyWpfApp\\MyWpfApp\\bin\\Debug')
clr.AddReference("MyWpfApp.dll")
```

However this produced the following error

```
FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'MyWpfApp.dll'.
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name) in C:\Users\Barton\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PySharp\trunk\pythonnet\src\runtime\moduleobject.cs:line 375
```

My knowledge of COM, Assemblies and typelibs are quite limited so I would appreciate if someone could help me understand what I need to do to access the DLL from python.

When I look at the entry in OLE/COM Object viewer, it points to the tlb file, not the dll, i.e.

```
Win32=D:\MyWorkSpace\testProgs\ATL_COM\WPF\MyWpfApp\MyWpfApp\bin\Debug\com.MyWpfApp.tlb
```

So, it is only the tlb file that is registered, not the class. When I run the LoadTypeLib class I am loading this from a path on my hard drive. I need the dll to be registered when I attempt to dispatch. Otherwise, if I can access this directly from a fixed path this would also be good but I don't know how to do this.

Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: if it's C# - can you use clr (python.net) and just load the assembly instead? might be easier...

Comment: I'm afraid this has to be regular python 2.X. Can Python.net be installed as a module?

Comment: yes, python.net can be installed as a module. http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is that the typelib is registered but not the class. So this python.net will not help me.

Comment: you dhouldn't have to register the class, if you use it in python.net as a C# assembly. it does need to be on the local drive though, or you run into weird permission issues. but otherwise, you can usually just do `import clr; sys.path.append('assembly_path'); clr.AddReference('AssemblyName'); import namespace` and it usually Just Works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding reference to the assembly but this failed, as discussed above. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46010/discussion-between-user1400716-and-corley-brigman)

Comment: pythonnet is hosted on github.com/pythonnet. The sourceforge link is outdated.